# Interaction with the legend D3.js grouped bar chart

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I plotted the Grouped Bar chart using D3.js.

```
Here:
```

https://jsfiddle.net/astropsych/uc3xy0bj/5/

I need to add dynamic interaction. So that when you hover over the legend, the corresponding values on the chart are highlighted, and when you click on the legend, the corresponding values disappear, and the chart is rebuilt. Help me please

Answer (score 0):

This is a very simple example of how you could achive this:

```js
var svg = d3.select("svg"),
  margin = { top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 220 },
  width = +svg.attr("width") - margin.left - margin.right,
  height = +svg.attr("height") - margin.top - margin.bottom;

const data = [
  { key: 'A', value: 20 },
  { key: 'B', value: 10 },
  { key: 'A', value: 8 },
  { key: 'B', value: 25 }
]

const keys = ['A', 'B']

const fade = (opacity) => {
  return e => {
    circles.style('opacity', d => d.key === e.target.id ? 1 : opacity)
    textLegend.style('opacity', d => d === e.target.id ? 1 : opacity)
    rectLegend.style('opacity', d => d === e.target.id ? 1 : opacity)
  }
}

const circles = svg
  .append('g')
  .selectAll('circle')
  .data(data)
  .join('circle')
  .attr('id', d => d.key)
  .attr('cx', (d, i) => 50 * i + 200)
  .attr('cy', 100)
  .attr('r', d => d.value)
  .attr('fill', d => d.key === 'A' ? 'red' : 'blue')
  .on('mouseover', fade(0.4))
  .on('mouseout', fade(1))

const textLegend = svg
  .append('g')
  .selectAll('text')
  .data(keys)
  .join('text')
  .attr('id', d => d)
  .attr('x', 100)
  .attr('y', (d, i) => i * 20 + 50)
  .text(d => d)
  .on('mouseover', fade(0.4))
  .on('mouseout', fade(1))

const rectLegend = svg
  .append('g')
  .selectAll('rect')
  .data(keys)
  .join('rect')
  .attr('id', d => d)
  .attr('x', 70)
  .attr('y', (d, i) => i * 20 + 40)
  .attr('width', 25)
  .attr('height', 10)
  .attr('fill', d => d === 'A' ? 'red' : 'blue')
  .on('mouseover', fade(0.4))
  .on('mouseout', fade(1))
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/style.css">
    <title>New Graph D3 - horizontal</title>
    <div class="chart">
        <svg width="800" height="600"></svg>
    </div>
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v6.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <script src="/script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```